# Change "Key word" (true/False) to "Yes/no" -Boolean C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change the "Keyword" of a boolean (true/false), I mean when I write at console.

For example:

What I want:

- Q: Was this song bought?
- R: Yes

What I have:

- Q: Was this song bought?
- R: True

I don't want to write "true" I want to write "yes" and that C# can understand it.

Code:

```
public void questionBought(string miQuestion)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    string temporal;
    bool variableBool;
    Console.WriteLine(miQuestion);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    temporal = Console.ReadLine();
    variableBool = Convert.ToBoolean(temporal);
    this.setBought(variableBool);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. You are reading into a string so just check what the string is equal to.

You can try something like this:

```
temporal = Console.ReadLine();
if (temporal.Equals("yes"))
{
   variableBool = true;
}
else
{
   variableBool = false;
}
```

Since String.Equals returns a bool value this can be shortened to:

```
temporal = Console.ReadLine();
variableBool = temporal.Equals("yes");
```

To further help this be more robust and accept any kind of casing, such as "Yes", "yes", "YeS" you can convert it to lowercase before checking equality:

```
temporal = Console.ReadLine();
variableBool = temporal.ToLower().Equals("yes");
```

There are many ways to solve this so try looking up some others.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it in a Razor View you can do the following:

```
@((item.variableBool) ? "Yes" : "No")
```

And if it is a nullable bool and assuming it always has a value:

```
@(((bool)item.variableBool) ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code:

```
variableBool = Convert.ToBoolean(temporal);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
variableBool = (temporal == "true");
```

Similarly, you can test for equality against any string you choose:

```
variableBool = (temporal == "yes");
```

Better yet, ignore case *(so user can type "yes", "YES", "Yes", etc)* during comparison by using:

```
variableBool = temporal.Equals("yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

C# by itself doesn't "understand" the human-intended meanings of strings.  Any string is just a string.  You can, however, *examine* those strings for expected values.  Something like this:

```
temporal = Console.ReadLine();
if (temporal.ToLower().Equals("yes"))
    variableBool = true;
else if (temporal.ToLower().Equals("no"))
    variableBool = false;
else
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse response.");
this.setBought(variableBool);
```

Comment: Note that for real code you'd put possible values into resource strings. And possibly have collection of "sounds like true" strings to match against rather than just yes/no.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: For "real code" there are a lot of improvements to be made to the OP's code.  But this should at least get him started.